# At the end of the Crippled God, what happens to the Crippled God?

Tags: malazan

We see Cotillion stabbing Kaminsod in the back, which I think WAS a good thing? Does he go back to wherever he came from?

Comment: Removed part of your title as its a spoiler that will show up on the front page.  otherwise +1

Comment: I have seen references that "It is unclear whether this act freed him to return to his own world, or slew him on the spot, but most probably the former as Kaminsod's new body was described as unsuitable for his journey home. " but that was fan speculation.

Comment: So, nothing definte? At all? Maybe any emotional hints say, The Crippled God being happy or something like that?

Comment: @SphoorthyNutulapati http://malazan.wikia.com/wiki/The_Crippled_God says *He is then released from his crippled body by Cotillion.* but I do not know if this is trustworthy enough for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It's left uncertain.

As far as I know, it's left vague on purpose.  It was stated somewhere in The Crippled God that Kaminsod's current body was unfit for travel back to his world which leaves me to believe that Cotillion acted in a way that would free Kaminsod from his body, allowing his soul to travel back to his world without issue.

We probably won't know for certain unless future works clarify or via the word of Erikson.  Due to a lack of evidence to the contrary, we're left to believe that's the intention behind Cotillion's actions.  Just as the characters however, we're left in the dark as to whether it succeeded or not.